# Laravel Query Builder "select" strange behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have a problem with the following code:

```
public function index() {
    $qObj = \DB::table('customers as c')
            ->join('companies_has_customers as chc', 'chc.comhc_cus_id', '=', 'c.cus_id')
            ->join('cuscategory as cc', 'chc.comhc_cca_id', '=', 'cc.cca_id')
            ->join('transactions as t','t.trn_cus_id', '=','c.cus_id')
            ->select('t.trn_id');  

    $qObj->where('comhc_com_id', '=', $this->companyId);


    $res = array(
        'count' => $qObj->count(),
        'items' => $qObj->get()
    );

    //print_r($this->showLastQuery());

    return parent::prepareResponse($res, 200, 'customers');
}
```

And this piece of code produces following SQL query:

```
select * from `customers` as `c` 
inner join `companies_has_customers` as `chc` on `chc`.`comhc_cus_id` = `c`.`cus_id`     
inner join `cuscategory` as `cc` on `chc`.`comhc_cca_id` = `cc`.`cca_id` 
inner join `transactions` as `t` on `t`.`trn_cus_id` = `c`.`cus_id` 
where comhc_com_id` = 1
```

**QUESTION:**

Why QueryBuilder produce `select *...` instead of `select t.trn_id...` as is requested in above syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in `$qObj->get(['t.trn_id'])` like this:

```
$res = array(
    'items' => $items = $qObj->get(['t.trn_id']),
    'count' => count($items) // count the cached $items
);
```

Instead of `select` ( Remove `select('t.trn_id')`).

Comment: Also there was a mistake, i missed the `$qObj->count()` and wrote `$qObj->get()` twice, updated it.

Answer (score 2):

Change the order:

```
$res = array(
    'items' => $qObj->get(),
    'count' => $qObj->count()
);
```

and it will work.

But better, instead of querying DB twice, do this:

```
$items = $qObj->get();

$res = array(
    'items' => $items,
    'count' => count($items)
);
```

The problem with your code is `count()` method behaviour - it resets the `columns` property (set with `select`), that's all.